# Using material not part of the 4 species to tie together the four species

Tags: sukkot

[image]  I forgot how we pasken do we say it's just mehudar to use "mino" or is it a chiyuv? the picture explains it all.

Comment: I usually rip off a couple of fronds from the outside of the lulav and make loops out of them. Easy. Quick. Min bemino.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26594/759

Answer (score 0):

Machloket Rabbi Meir an Rabbi Yehuda in 3rd chapter mishna 8: we pasken as Rabbi Meir who allows outside of 4 minim. The reason is that tying is not an obligation for RM so tying material is not a part of the mitsva and tying with a fift species is not bal tosif, a prohibited addition.

Summary: Good 100%. Lechaora no matter to hiddur.

The mitsva to make a knot for RM is itself mishum Hiddur, ze keli veanvehu. See SA OC 651, 1

> ומצוה לאגדם בקשר גמור, דהיינו ב' קשרים זה על זה, משום נוי; ויכול לאגדם במין אחר.    ‏